# How to parse a highlight syntax for complex file in intellij plugin?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

I have custom file like this:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <script type="groovy">
            import com.example.SampleClass;

            return new SampleClass().returnSomeValue() &amp;&amp; Math.random() > 0.5;
        </script>
    </element>
</root>
```

How can I implement correct syntax highlight for different parts of this file?
Is it possible to do syntax checking for xml and groovy separately and show proper errors?
How to "show" `&amp` as `&`?

Is custom language implementation needed or can I reuse `com.intellij.lang.xml.XMLLanguage` and `GroovyLanugage`?

Can you please point me to some direction? I've read about PSI, tried to go through some existing plugins but I have no idea how to implement it correctly.

Some articles, examples, documentation or something would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your code into a .xml file, the xml highlighting should appear automatically. It is also possible to map other file extensions to the xml file type using `Preferences | Editor | File Types`.

You probably want to look into *Language Injections*. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Groovy code and invoke `Inject language or reference`. Now select Groovy (type the first letters for quick search). At this point you should have temporary highlighting of the Groovy code. This can be made permanent by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again and invoking `Language Injection Settings`. Here you can specify for example an XPath expression like `//script[@type="groovy"]` to always highlight such xml content as Groovy code.